Build Error: 'RNFastOpencvSpec.h' file not found when using react-native-fast-opencv
I'm facing a build error when integrating react-native-fast-opencv into my React Native project. The issue occurs during the iOS build process in Xcode and blocks the app from compiling. The error is:
'RNFastOpencvSpec.h' file not found
In file included from ProjectRootDirectory/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/ios/FastOpencv.mm:1:

What I Tried:
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Deleted the Derived Data folder and cleaned the build folder.

Rebuilt the project in Xcode.

Deleted the node_modules folder, Pods folder, and Podfile.lock file.

Reinstalled dependencies by running:
yarn install

cd ios && pod install


Downgraded react-native-fast-opencv to version ^0.2.13.

In my ios folder i have also tried
RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install


Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue.
Additional Information
Library Version: "react-native-fast-opencv": "^0.3.0"
React Native Version: "react-native": "0.76.1"
Node Version: v18.18.0
Yarn Version: 3.6.4
Xcode Version: Version 16.0
macOS Version: 15.0.1

I was able to resolve the issue with the

'RNFastOpencvSpec.h' file not found

error during the iOS build process in Xcode.
The problem was related to the version (^0.3.0) of react-native-fast-opencv with react native(0.76.1).After contacting the library maintainer, they pointed out that the issue was fixed in version v0.3.1.
I updated to this newer version, and the error was resolved successfully.
Solution:
Update react-native-fast-opencv to version v0.3.1 or above.
Clean and rebuild the project.
Hope this helps others encountering the same issue!
